# Preventing automatic Hy@writebookmark in \addcontentsline

Tags: hyperref, package-writing, bookmarks

As a result of my (yet to be published ;-) package with questions and solutions I came across some problems, that are connected to sectioning of a document, say, a book with chapters/sections/subsections etc.

As such, in the way I was finding a solution, there is a *cloning* of sectioning commands with titles etc. to an external file and reading it at the end of the compilation run, via `\input`.

The, say, `\chapter` command has to be redefined to this, and it will first produce the ordinary chapter and later on the cloned chapter, via `\immediate\write\LaTeXStandardChapter` (see MWE for definitions please). As long as the delayed chapters have accumulated chapter numbers, there is no problem. `\addcontentsline` adds them nicely to the toc and generates a bookmark, when `hyperref` package is used.

Well, I do not want to have accumulated chapter numbers, I rather want to start them over again, such as

> Question part: Chapter First  ---->   Section First of First
>
> Cloned part: Cloned Chapter First --> Cloned Section First of First

etc. i.e. the chapter numbers have to be reset before reading the cloned content file.

Now the `\LaTeXStandardChapter{...}` command will add a content line --> this is fine.

But the bookmarks are wrong, since they are created from the chapter number 1 etc, which is present twice --> the click on the bookmark will go to the wrong place!

Obviously, I have to disable the automatic generation of the bookmark made by `\addcontentsline`, i.e. dropping `\Hy@writebookmark` in a group and add the bookmark 'manually'.

All this works, but is there some nicer way to this?

Here is my code: (Part of a larger framework, only the relevant parts are shown or shortened to quick usage)

```
\documentclass[12pt,paper=a4]{book}


\RequirePackage{etoolbox}%
\RequirePackage{xcolor}%
\RequirePackage{morewrites}
\RequirePackage[bookmarksopen=true,bookmarksopenlevel=2]{hyperref}%
\RequirePackage{bookmark}%


\newwrite\CloneChapter%

\let\LaTeXStandardChapter\chapter%
\makeatletter
\newrobustcmd{\unstarredchapter@noopt}[1]{%
\unstarredchapter[#1]{#1}%  Call the version with the optional first arg%
}% End of \unstarredchapter@noopt



\newrobustcmd{\unstarredchapter@opt}[2][]{%
\LaTeXStandardChapter[#1]{#2}% Normal Chapter, the source of the clone%
\immediate\write\CloneChapter{%
\string\LaTeXStandardChapter[]{\unexpanded{Explanation -- #2}}%  Prevent an entry to the toc from the cloned chapter
\string\phantomsection%
\string\begingroup
\string\renewcommand{\unexpanded{\Hy@writebookmark}}[5]{}%   Drop this "wrong" bookmark
\string\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\unexpanded{\protect\numberline{\thechapter}}{\unexpanded{Explanation -- #1}}}%
\string\endgroup
\string\pdfbookmark[0,color=red]{\unexpanded{Explanation #1}}{cloned::chapter::bookmark::\thechapter}% Manually write the bookmark
}% End of \immediate\write
}% End of \unstarredchapter@opt


% 'Rewrite' the starred chapter, to cool down `\tableofcontents` ;-)
\newrobustcmd{\starredchapter}[1]{%
\LaTeXStandardChapter*{#1}%
}%

\newrobustcmd{\unstarredchapter}{%
\@ifnextchar[{\unstarredchapter@opt}{\unstarredchapter@noopt}
}%


\renewcommand{\chapter}{%
\@ifstar{\starredchapter}{\unstarredchapter}%
}%



\makeatother

\AtBeginDocument{%
\immediate\openout\CloneChapter=\jobname.clone%
\immediate\write\CloneChapter{%
  \string\makeatletter%
  \string\setcounter{chapter}{0}%
}%
}%

\AtEndDocument{%
\immediate\closeout\CloneChapter%
}%

\newrobustcmd{\CollectClonedChapter}{%
\part{Explanations}%
\setcounter{chapter}{0}%
\IfFileExists{\jobname.clone}{\input{\jobname.clone}}{%
}%
}%


\newcounter{somecounter}[chapter]

\newrobustcmd{\MyCommand}[2]{%
\refstepcounter{somecounter}%
\textbf{Example \thesomecounter:}

\noindent#1
\hrule%
\immediate\write\CloneChapter{%
\expandafter\string\unexpanded{\textbf{Explanation to Example \number\value{chapter}.\number\value{somecounter}}}

}%
\immediate\write\CloneChapter{%
\noindent
}%
\immediate\write\CloneChapter{%
\expandafter\string\unexpanded{#2}%
}%
}


\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\part{Questions}%

\chapter{Original Chapter Number One}

\MyCommand{Foo}{Well, this was foo}%


\chapter[Short Original 2]{Original Chapter Number Two}

\MyCommand{And now for something completely different}{Who used that line very often?}

\CollectClonedChapter%

\end{document}
```

[image]

**Edit**

The repeated write of `\renewcommand{\Hy@writebookmark}` is a little overstressing -- in my original framework, I wrapped `\addcontentsline` in another command which does the redefinition. I omitted it for simplicity here.

**Obviously there is no answer to this question :-(**

Comment: Look at macro `\etoctoccontentsline` which, in its non-starred incarnation expands to `\Etoc@addtocontents` on line `1127` of `etoc`'s code in `etoc.pdf`. It shows how to add something to the `.toc` file without intervention of `hyperref` which patches only `\addcontentsline` and not `\addtocontents`.

Comment: Here is the relevant extract from `etoc`'s doc: *The
etoc command `\etoctoccontentsline{..}{..}` is provided as a substitute to `\addcontentsline{toc}{..}{..}`: this is to avoid the patching which is done by hyperref to
`\addcontentsline` in its process of creation of bookmarks.*

Comment: @jfbu: Are you ready to provide an answer? ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an altogether different approach, but still adopting the general structure of your code.

One remark: I didn't know about package [morewrites](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/morewrites) and decided not to use it. Indeed it modifies my expectations about how opening and closing file streams work in `TeX`. It allows it seems to use a read stream on a file which has not been closed yet.

As coloured bookmarks are not rendered in all pdf viewers, exceptionally I used `Acrobat Reader` for this answer.

```
\documentclass[12pt,paper=a4]{scrbook}

\RequirePackage{etoolbox}
\RequirePackage{xcolor}
%% \RequirePackage{morewrites}%% modifies our habits with respect to opened
%% and closed file streams. Too unsettling for a (in the process of becoming
%% old) guy.
\RequirePackage[bookmarksopen=true,bookmarksopenlevel=2]{hyperref}
\RequirePackage{bookmark}


\newwrite\CloneChapter

\let\LaTeXStandardChapter\chapter

\makeatletter

\renewcommand{\chapter}{\@ifstar{\starredchapter}{\unstarredchapter}}%

\newrobustcmd{\unstarredchapter}
             {\@ifnextchar[{\unstarredchapter@opt}{\unstarredchapter@noopt}}

\newrobustcmd{\unstarredchapter@noopt}[1]{%
     \unstarredchapter[#1]{#1}%  Call the version with the optional first arg%
}

\newrobustcmd{\unstarredchapter@opt}[2][]{%
    \LaTeXStandardChapter[#1]{#2}% Normal Chapter, the source of the clone
    \immediate\write\CloneChapter 
      {\string\LaTeXStandardChapter[Explanation -- #1]{Explanation -- #2}}%
}

\newrobustcmd{\starredchapter}[1]{\LaTeXStandardChapter*{#1}}%

\makeatother

\AtBeginDocument{\immediate\openout\CloneChapter=\jobname.clone }

% without morewrites, we can not wait EndDocument to close the file
% and then reopen it
% \AtEndDocument {\immediate\closeout\CloneChapter }%

\newrobustcmd{\CollectClonedChapter}{%
    \immediate\closeout\CloneChapter 
    \part{Explanations}
    \edef \ChapterCount {\arabic{chapter}}%
    \renewcommand \thechapter {\the\numexpr\value{chapter}-\ChapterCount\relax}%
    \bookmarksetup{color=red}%
    \makeatletter
    \IfFileExists{\jobname.clone}{\input{\jobname.clone}}
                                 {CLONE FILE WAS SWALLOWED SOMEWHERE!}%
    \makeatother
}%


\newcounter{somecounter}[chapter]

\newrobustcmd{\MyCommand}[2]{%
    \refstepcounter{somecounter}%
    \textbf{Example \thesomecounter:}

    \noindent #1
    \hrule
    \immediate\write\CloneChapter {%
        \string\textbf{Explanation to Example 
                        \arabic{chapter}.\arabic{somecounter}}

        \noindent #2
    }% end of \write
}


\begin{document}
\bookmark[named=FirstPage]{Title page}

\tableofcontents

\part{Questions}

\chapter[Short 1]{Original Chapter Number One}

\MyCommand{Foo}{Well, this was foo}

\chapter[Short 2]{Original Chapter Number Two}

\MyCommand{And now for something completely different}
          {Who used that line very often?} 


\CollectClonedChapter

\end{document}
```

[image: hupfer clones]

Comment: a `\makeatletter/\makeatother` pair in `\CollectClonedChapter` is a remnant of an earlier code version.

Comment: `\unstarredchapter` in `\unstarredchapter@noopt` from OP's code should be `\unstarredchapter@opt` for efficiency.

Comment: I'll take a look later on, thanks in advance

Comment: Bye the way: Do you want to have a look on http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/222578/automatically-adjust-colour-of-current-part-when-displaying-local-table-of-contents?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I will (when I get some time, will be soon). Thanks for drawing my attention to it.