# Customize single \part sectioning command with correct TOC links in PDF?

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning, hyperref

I want to use one `\part` (so, not all) as numbered sectioning command (so, no `\part*`), but I want to have a separate entry for the actual part title, separate one for the TOC typeset in PDF, and separate entry for the TOC in/as PDF bookmarks.

With the following MWE, I can achieve almost all that:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{hyperref}

% http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2785260/hide-an-entry-from-toc-in-latex
\newcommand{\nocontentsline}[3]{}
\newcommand{\tocless}[2]{\bgroup\let\addcontentsline=\nocontentsline#1{#2}\egroup}

% copy of hyperref.sty \phantomsection:
\makeatletter
\def\phantompart{%
  \Hy@MakeCurrentHrefAuto{part}%
  \Hy@raisedlink{\hyper@anchorstart{\@currentHref}\hyper@anchorend}%
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter*{Important notes}

A very important part comes ahead.

\section{A numbered section}

This should show in the TOC, too...

\def\ptitle{Test title}

\tocless\part{%
  \texorpdfstring{%
    % tex string for \part itself
    Introduction: \emph{\ptitle} - \textbf{and more}. %
  }{%
    % pdf string for PDF Bookmarks TOC
    Introduction: \ptitle%
  }%
}
% tex string for the PDF typeset TOC
% \refstepcounter{part} - already done!
% \phantompart % for correct links in \addcontentsline
% \thepart \hspace{1em} from def of @part in book.cls:
\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{\thepart\hspace{1em} Introduction: \emph{\ptitle}.}

Something in this part...

\chapter{Inside the part}

The chapter inside the part...

\section{More inside the part}

The section more inside the part...

\end{document}
```

... except the TOC links are wrong; without the `\phantompart` (implemented by analogy to `\phantomsection` which has been said to fix these kind of issues), the `test.toc` file contains a correctly named link (`part.1`), but wrong page number (7):

```
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {0.1}A numbered section}{3}{section.0.1}
\contentsline {part}{I\hspace {1em} Introduction: \emph {Test title}.}{7}{part.1}
\contentsline {chapter}{\numberline {1}Inside the part}{9}{chapter.1}
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {1.1}More inside the part}{9}{section.1.1}
```

... and with the `\phantompart` uncommented, it's even worse - a wrongly named link (`part.3`), and wrong page number (7):

```
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {0.1}A numbered section}{3}{section.0.1}
\contentsline {part}{I\hspace {1em} Introduction: \emph {Test title}.}{7}{part.3}
\contentsline {chapter}{\numberline {1}Inside the part}{9}{chapter.1}
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {1.1}More inside the part}{9}{section.1.1}
```

I'd want the link to be called `part.1`, and to point to page 5, which is where the part title actually appears:

[image: test.png]

... and what you get in the .toc file (`...{5}{part.1}`) if you don't use `\tocless` and `\addcontentsline`.

So, how could I achieve the entry

```
\contentsline {part}{I\hspace {1em} Introduction: \emph {Test title}.}{5}{part.1}
```

... automatically in .toc, while having all three custom entries for a numbered `\part`?

Comment: I've added a better version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could be a possible solution, by providing a `\enhancedpart` command, having an 3rd argument containing the bookmark title.

Since `hyperref` automatically adds the bookmarks via `\addcontentsline`, this has to be kicked out. The `bookmark` package provides some features, but the destination key has to be set then. This is automatically done using a `\hypertarget{...}` to the part title. (I have posted a question some while ago concerning to switch off/bypass this feature of `\addcontentsline`, but it is still unanswered so far :-( [Preventing automatic Hy@writebookmark in \addcontentsline](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/186108/preventing-automatic-hywritebookmark-in-addcontentsline))

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{xcolor}%
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{etoolbox}%

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\enhancedpart@opt}[3][]{%
  \begingroup%
  \renewcommand{\Hy@writebookmark}[5]{}{}{}{}{}% Drop it%
  \phantomsection%
  \part[#1]{\hypertarget{bookmark::\number\value{part}}{}{#2}}
  \bookmark[level=-1,color={blue},dest={bookmark::\number\value{part}}]{#3}%
  \endgroup%
}%

\newcommand{\enhancedpart@noopt}[2]{%
  \enhancedpart[#1]{#1}{#2}%
}%

\newcommand{\enhancedpart}{%
\@ifnextchar[{\enhancedpart@opt}{\enhancedpart@noopt}
}%

\makeatother


\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{bookmark}


% http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2785260/hide-an-entry-from-toc-in-latex
\newcommand{\nocontentsline}[3]{}
\newcommand{\tocless}[2]{\bgroup\let\addcontentsline=\nocontentsline#1{#2}\egroup}

% copy of hyperref.sty \phantomsection:
%\makeatletter
%\def\phantompart{%
%  \Hy@MakeCurrentHrefAuto{part}%
%  \Hy@raisedlink{\hyper@anchorstart{\@currentHref}\hyper@anchorend}%
%}
%\makeatother


\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter*{Important notes}

A very important part comes ahead.

\section{A numbered section}

This should show in the TOC, too...


\enhancedpart{Test Title}{Title for bookmark}



Something in this part...

\chapter{Inside the part}

The chapter inside the part...

\section{More inside the part}

The section more inside the part...

\enhancedpart[Another title for the ToC]{A part for the book}{And even another title for the bookmarks}

\end{document}
```

### Other version with `xparse` approach

In this way, the `\enhancedpart` command works as `\part[]{}` and does not generate a bookmark entry, or `\part{}[]` will use the `{}` argument as Toc entry, but `[...]` for the bookmark entry.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{xcolor}%
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{xparse}

\makeatletter
\NewDocumentCommand{\enhancedpart}{+o+m+o}{%
    \begingroup
    \renewcommand{\Hy@writebookmark}[5]{}{}{}{}{}%
    \phantomsection
    \IfNoValueTF{#3}{%
      \IfNoValueTF{#1}{%
        \part{#2}%
      }{%
        \part[#1]{#2}%
      }%
    }{%
      \IfNoValueTF{#1}{%
        \part{#2}\hypertarget{bookmark::\number\value{part}}{}
        }{%
          \part[#1]{#2}\hypertarget{bookmark::\number\value{part}}{}%
        }%          
      \bookmark[level=-1,color={blue},dest={bookmark::\number\value{part}}]{#3}
    }%
    \endgroup%
  }%
\makeatother

\usepackage[bookmarksnumbered=false]{hyperref}%
\usepackage{bookmark}%


\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter*{Important notes}

A very important part comes ahead.

\section{A numbered section}

This should show in the TOC, too...


% Toc entry different from main entry, No entry to the bookmarks
\enhancedpart[Test Title for Toc]{Part title}



Something in this part...

\chapter{Inside the part}

The chapter inside the part...

\section{More inside the part}

The section more inside the part...

% Toc entry, main entry, bookmark entry%
\enhancedpart[Another title for the ToC]{A new part for the book}[And even another title for the bookmarks]

% Toc entry the same as main entry and some bookmark%

\enhancedpart{A part for the book}[And even another title for the bookmarks, but the same for the TOC]

% Toc entry and main entry alike, no bookmarks
\enhancedpart{The ultimate part}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Many thanks @ChristianHupfer - turns out, `\part` has an optional argument, where `\texorpdfstring` can be used to control all this without much hacking (see my [post below](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/213191/2595)); but I'll accept this because I like the new command approach that has three arguments. Cheers!

Comment: @sdaau: A better approach (had no time ;-)) would be a key-value approach and even the bookmark title as a 2nd possible optional argument, via `xparse`

Comment: @sdaau: All sectioning commands have this optional argument which must be catched somehow

Answer (score 2):

The end of the ToC clears the page (two pages for two-sided). So the `\addcontentsline` is being executed when TeX is already on page 7. To avoid this, you can add the contents line *first*, manually clearing the pages to ensure that the ToC does not need to start a new page:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{hyperref}

% http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2785260/hide-an-entry-from-toc-in-latex
\newcommand{\nocontentsline}[3]{}
\newcommand{\tocless}[2]{\bgroup\let\addcontentsline\nocontentsline#1{#2}\egroup}

% copy of hyperref.sty \phantomsection:
\makeatletter
\def\phantompart{%
  \Hy@MakeCurrentHrefAuto{part}%
  \Hy@raisedlink{\hyper@anchorstart{\@currentHref}\hyper@anchorend}%
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

  \tableofcontents

  \chapter*{Important notes}

  A very important part comes ahead.

  \section{A numbered section}

  This should show in the TOC, too...

  \def\ptitle{Test title}

  \cleardoublepage
  \addcontentsline{toc}{part}{\thepart\hspace{1em} Introduction: \emph{\ptitle}.}%
  \tocless\part{%
    \texorpdfstring{%
      Introduction: \emph{\ptitle} - \textbf{and more}. %
    }{%
      Introduction: \ptitle%
    }%
  }

  Something in this part...

  \chapter{Inside the part}

  The chapter inside the part...

  \section{More inside the part}

  The section more inside the part...

\end{document}
```

[image: ToC]

Comment: Many thanks for that, @cfr - now I finally understand why I was getting "7" as a page number there `:)` I just realized (my [post below](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/213191/2595)) that I can use the optional argument of `\part` to do this; but otherwise this is even more in the spirit of the MWE - so I'm really undetermined if I should change the accept here! `:)` I'll have to return to that later, though - thanks again and cheers!

Comment: @sdau That's for you to decide ;). But I'm glad the explanation helped! All sectioning commands have this optional argument...

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think I got it; first, found like this that `\part` - or rather `\@part` - actually has an optional argument:

```
$ texdef -t latex -c book part -f
\part first defined in "book.cls".

\part:
\long macro:->\if@openright \cleardoublepage \else \clearpage \fi \thispagestyle {plain}\if@twocolumn \onecolumn \@tempswatrue \else \@tempswafalse \fi \null \vfil \secdef \@part \@spart 

$ texdef -t latex -c book @part -f
\@part first defined in "book.cls".

\@part:
macro:[#1]#2->\ifnum \c@secnumdepth >-2\relax \refstepcounter {part}\addcontentsline {toc}{part}{\thepart \hspace {1em}#1}\else \addcontentsline {toc}{part}{#1}\fi \markboth {}{}{\centering \interlinepenalty \@M \normalfont \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >-2\relax \huge \bfseries \partname \nobreakspace \thepart \par \vskip 20\p@ \fi \Huge \bfseries #2\par }\@endpart
```

This optional argument is used exactly for setting the TOC entries - and using the `\texorpdfstring` in there, we can control either the PDF-typeset TOC, or the PDF Bookmark/Index TOC. So, the solution is to change this part in the OP MWE:

```
% ...
\def\ptitle{Test title}

% the \part optional argument handles either:
% pdf-typeset TOC (\contentsline), or PDF Bookmark/Index TOC!
\part[%
  \texorpdfstring{%
    Introduction: A \emph{\ptitle}.%
  }{%
    % pdf string for PDF Bookmarks TOC
    Introduction: B \ptitle%
  }%
]{%
  % tex string for \part itself
  Introduction: \emph{\ptitle} - \textbf{and more}. %
}

Something in this part...
% ...
```

So, no `\tocless` is needed; nor a separate `\addcontentsline` - and inside the .toc file, the expected entry is generated:

```
\contentsline {part}{I\hspace {1em}Introduction: A \emph {Test title}.}{5}{part.1}
```

... which also means the the correct page number is shown in TOC.

Hope that was it...