# Automatically adjust colour of current part when displaying local table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents, etoc

I produce course books on a photocopier. However, the photocopier can staple no more than 50 sheets in a booklet, and I don't always write later parts of the books in advance of the start date of the course. (If too few students enrol, the course gets cancelled.)

Hence, I split the books into parts. Each part has a separate cover and contents page. To simplify somewhat, the way this is supposed to work is that

- the main contents is a regular listing of everything;
- the contents of parts 2+ of the book exclude anything in parts which come after the current part, and they print the contents of anything in parts which come before the current part in a different colour.

To do this, I use `etoc` for multiple tables of contents, and some hackery of the `toc` file:

```
\documentclass[oneside,openany]{book}
\usepackage{etoc,xparse,xcolor}

\makeatletter
\newcounter{packetcount}
\setcounter{packetcount}{1}
\NewDocumentCommand\packetpart {}{%
  \clearpage%
  \thispagestyle{empty}%
  \stepcounter{packetcount}%
  Title page goes here
  \clearpage\thispagestyle{empty}\cleardoublepage
    \tableofcontents
  \clearpage\thispagestyle{empty}\cleardoublepage}
\newcommand*{\tocfade}{%
  \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\colorlet{toccol}{fadedtoc}}%
  \addtocontents{toc}{\color{toccol}}}
\newcommand*{\tocon}{%
  \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\colorlet{toccol}{ontoc}}%
  \addtocontents{toc}{\color{toccol}}}
\newcommand*{\tocoff}{%
  \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\colorlet{toccol}{offtoc}}%
  \addtocontents{toc}{\color{toccol}}}
\def\addcontentsline#1#2#3{%
  \addtocontents{#1}{\protect\contentsline{#2}{#3}{\color{toccol}\thepage}}}
\newcommand*{\maintoc}{%
  \colorlet{origfadedtoc}{fadedtoc}%
  \colorlet{origontoc}{ontoc}%
  \colorlet{origofftoc}{offtoc}%
  \colorlet{fadedtoc}{black}%
  \colorlet{ontoc}{black}%
  \colorlet{offtoc}{black}%
  \tableofcontents
  \colorlet{fadedtoc}{origfadedtoc}%
  \colorlet{ontoc}{origontoc}%
  \colorlet{offtoc}{origofftoc}}
\makeatother
\colorlet{toccol}{black}
\colorlet{fadedtoc}{yellow}
\colorlet{ontoc}{blue}
\colorlet{offtoc}{white}
\begin{document}

  Main title page goes here.
  \maintoc
  \tocfade

  \chapter{Chapter One}
  \section{A section}
  \section{Another section}

  \tocon
  \packetpart
  \chapter{Chapter Two}
  \section{A middle section}
  \section{Another middle section}

  \tocoff
  \packetpart
  \chapter{Chapter Three}
  \section{A later section}

\end{document}
```

This works as expected. The main contents looks like this:

[image: main toc]

and the contents for part 2 looks like this:

[image: contents for part 2]

However, the contents for all the other parts is just like the contents for part 2 because I've written the colour changes to the `.toc` file at particular points, and the `\tableofcontents` reads the same code no matter which part is the currently active one.

This means that I must manually move the `\tocon` and `\tocoff` commands in order to produce different parts of the book, and must recompile the file twice each time. For example, to produce the third part, I must delete the `\tocon` command and replace the `\tocoff` command by `\tocon`, and recompile twice to get everything resolved properly. This is a pain.

I was hoping to use `etoc` to avoid this. In particular, I was hoping to work some magic in `\packetpart` which would modify the display of `\tableofcontents` for just that part of the book in the desired way. One attraction of `etoc` is that it does ***not*** need additional auxiliary files, of which I am already writing a great number.

I have figured out how to avoid the need for `\tocoff` using `etoc`'s notion of `tag`:

```
\documentclass[oneside,openany]{book}% made oneside/openany just to reduce pages in test file - actual use case is double-sided
\usepackage{etoc,xparse,xcolor}

\makeatletter
\newcounter{packetcount}
\setcounter{packetcount}{1}
\NewDocumentCommand\packetpart {}{%
  \clearpage%
  \thispagestyle{empty}%
  \stepcounter{packetcount}%
  \def\cfr@toctag@packetpart{packetpart\thepacketcount}%
  \expandafter\etocdepthtag.toc{\cfr@toctag@packetpart}%
  Title page goes here
  \clearpage\thispagestyle{empty}\cleardoublepage
    \etocsettagdepth{\cfr@toctag@packetpart}{1}%
    \stepcounter{packetcount}%
    \def\cfr@toctag@nextpacketpart{packetpart\thepacketcount}%
    \etocsettagdepth{\cfr@toctag@nextpacketpart}{none}%
    \addtocounter{packetcount}{-1}%
    \tableofcontents
  \clearpage\thispagestyle{empty}\cleardoublepage}
\newcommand*{\tocfade}{%
  \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\colorlet{toccol}{fadedtoc}}%
  \addtocontents{toc}{\color{toccol}}}
\newcommand*{\tocon}{%
  \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\colorlet{toccol}{ontoc}}%
  \addtocontents{toc}{\color{toccol}}}
\def\addcontentsline#1#2#3{%
  \addtocontents{#1}{\protect\contentsline{#2}{#3}{\color{toccol}\thepage}}}
\newcommand*{\maintoc}{%
  \colorlet{origfadedtoc}{fadedtoc}%
  \colorlet{origontoc}{ontoc}%
  \colorlet{fadedtoc}{black}%
  \colorlet{ontoc}{black}%
  \tableofcontents
  \colorlet{fadedtoc}{origfadedtoc}%
  \colorlet{ontoc}{origontoc}}
\makeatother
\colorlet{toccol}{black}
\colorlet{fadedtoc}{yellow}% just for clarity in the example
\colorlet{ontoc}{blue}% just for clarity in the example
\begin{document}

  Main title page goes here.
  \maintoc
  \tocfade

  \chapter{Chapter One}
  \section{A section}
  \section{Another section}

  \tocon
  \packetpart
  \chapter{Chapter Two}
  \section{A middle section}
  \section{Another middle section}

  \packetpart
  \chapter{Chapter Three}
  \section{A later section}

\end{document}
```

produces contents for part 2:

[image: contents for part 2 with tags]

and part 3:

[image: contents for part 3 with tags]

However, I can't come up with a way to change the colours appropriately. That is, I can't make the listing for part 2 be yellow when displayed as part of the contents in part 3.

I must admit that I am far from comfortable with `etoc` and I have somewhat limited experience with it, so if there is something obvious in its extensive manual, please just tell me and I'll happily delete this question.

If not, is there a way to do this? That is, is there a semi-reasonable/practicable way to do this?

Note: Before anybody comments on it, I am ***not*** really using yellow, blue and black in the contents. I am actually using black and grey. But I thought more dramatic changes of colour would make the example clearer.

Comment: Perhaps the `\etocaftercontentshook` could be of use here?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Thanks. I can't see how to make that work. The examples I've found in the manual see to affect what comes right after the ToC rather than the display of part of the ToC itself. I thought I might be able to use `\etocsetstyle` with the level specified using the tag but `\etocsetstyle` appears not to like any level name which includes a number (even specifying the level as, say, `1` breaks it). How were you thinking `\etocaftercontentshook` might be used here?

Comment: For resetting the colours? I must admit, that I have not looked deeply enough into that manual. The package author (jfbu) is also here on TeX.SX! I can leave him a note?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Mmm... As far as I can see, you can't use it except to affect the entire contents listing, though. So I don't think that will work. If you have a way to leave jfbu a note, that would be excellent - thanks!

Comment: He answered one of my questions recently so I had the chance to leave (an off-topic) comment to him to have a look on your question. He promised to look after it.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Thanks again. The package can do so much that it is hard to get to grips with!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I propose the following, which is a lighter method, but admittedly a bit hackish.

The [etoc](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/etoc) `tag`'s use is to decide which portions of the TOC get printed. If we were to follow this path here, we would have as in the OP's code to add tags at each new *packet*, but also we would have to find way to set the levels of all further packets to invisible, which is possibly ok in a document with  a few such packets, but anyhow somewhat cumbersome.

> an update uses tags nevertheless, but not for colour management. As pointed out in comments, tags are only for locally influencing from inside the `.toc` file the `tocdepth` counter, in a dynamically customizable way. To have them influence things like colours would mean hacking an internal `etoc` macro.

A simpler way is to have some way to tell `etoc` to stop here and now the current toc. There does not seem to be such a functionality already implemented hence I had to do it (via `\cfr@removetonil`, the `\AtEndDocument` hook, and the code in `\maintoc`).

The management of colors is simpler, we just need to store in the `.toc` file some number and compare its value to the then current value in the document at the location where the colored toc is to be displayed.

There is an annoyance with the standard class styles for sections which insist on resetting the color of the page numbers, I go around this with a local re-definition of `\normalcolor` which is a bit brutal.

```
\documentclass[oneside,openany]{book}% made oneside/openany just to reduce pages in test file - actual use case is double-sided
\usepackage{etoc,xparse,xcolor}

\makeatletter

\newcounter{packetcount}

\setcounter{packetcount}{1}

\NewDocumentCommand\packetpart {}{%
  \clearpage
  \thispagestyle{empty}%
  \stepcounter{packetcount}%
  Title page goes here
  \clearpage\thispagestyle{empty}\cleardoublepage
  \addtocontents {toc}{\protect\cfr@toccolormanager {\arabic{packetcount}}}%
    \tableofcontents
  \clearpage\thispagestyle{empty}\cleardoublepage 
}

\def\cfr@nil {}
\long\def\cfr@removetonil #1\cfr@nil {}

\newcommand*\cfrtoccolormanager [1]{%
   \ifnum #1<\value{packetcount}\color{fadedtoc}%
   \else\ifnum #1=\value{packetcount}\color{ontoc}\else
   \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\cfr@removetonil\fi\fi }

\AtBeginDocument {\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\cfr@toccolormanager {1}}}

\AtEndDocument   {\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\cfr@nil }}

\newcommand*\maintoc {\let\cfr@toccolormanager\@gobble
                      \tableofcontents
                      \let\cfr@toccolormanager\cfrtoccolormanager 
% this awful thing next is because of disputable habit of the standard 
% classes to reset the color when printing the page numbers (and
% only the page numbers!) in the toc, for the sections, but not
% the chapters... this is less drastic than redefining \addcontentsline
% which would have then to be made compatible with hyperref!
%
% full usage of etoc would go with a customization of the toc line
% styles, hence the problem would not even exist.
      \renewcommand*\etocaftertitlehook{\let\normalcolor\relax}%
}
\makeatother

\colorlet{toccol}{black}
\colorlet{fadedtoc}{yellow}% just for clarity in the example
\colorlet{ontoc}{blue}% just for clarity in the example

\begin{document}

  Main title page goes here.

  \maintoc

  \chapter{Chapter One}
  \section{A section}
  \section{Another section}

  \packetpart
  \chapter{Chapter Two}
  \section{A middle section}
  \section{Another middle section}

  \packetpart
  \chapter{Chapter Three}
  \section{A later section}

\end{document}
```

Sorry about how the yellow appears on these transparent images:

> [image: TOC main]
>
> ---
>
> [image: TOC 2]
>
> ---
>
> [image: TOC 3]

---

---

Here is a method using the etoc so-called tags. The colour management is done as above. The code is simpler, we don't need to define a delimited macro nor have to put some token at the end of the `.toc` file. I leave the method of resolution of the page number colour question to the liking of the user: I think `tocloft` would allow full control, and naturally `etoc` does too, but one would have to define the line styles then. Here, everything is according to the class defaults.

The thing is not completely automatized, for simplicity sake: see the definition of `\maintoc` for the needed `manual` things to do.

*nota bene*: in one of my comments below I gave a wrong indication regarding `\etocsettagdepth`. The correct thing is to set here its second argument to `all` (or at least `section`)  not to `chapter`. See the code.

```
\documentclass[oneside,openany]{book}% made oneside/openany just to reduce pages in test file - actual use case is double-sided
\usepackage{etoc,xparse,xcolor}

\makeatletter

\newcounter{packetcount}

\setcounter{packetcount}{1}

\NewDocumentCommand\packetpart {}{%
  \clearpage
  \thispagestyle{empty}%
  \stepcounter{packetcount}%
  Title page goes here
  \clearpage\thispagestyle{empty}\cleardoublepage
  \etocdepthtag.toc {packet\arabic{packetcount}}%
% next is to show all sections, subsections... of the next chapter,
%  up to the level restrained by the global tocdepth setting:
  \etocsettagdepth {packet\arabic{packetcount}}{all}%
  \addtocontents {toc}{\protect\cfr@toccolormanager {\arabic{packetcount}}}%
    \tableofcontents
  \clearpage\thispagestyle{empty}\cleardoublepage 
}

\newcommand*\cfrtoccolormanager [1]{%
   \ifnum #1<\value{packetcount}\color{fadedtoc}%
   \else\ifnum #1=\value{packetcount}\color{ontoc}\fi\fi }

\AtBeginDocument {\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\cfr@toccolormanager {1}}}

\newcommand*\maintoc {\let\cfr@toccolormanager\@gobble
                      \tableofcontents
                      \let\cfr@toccolormanager\cfrtoccolormanager 
    \etocsettagdepth {packet2}{none}%
    \etocsettagdepth {packet3}{none}%
    \etocsettagdepth {packet4}{none}%
% repeat with until the last packet
}
\makeatother

\colorlet{toccol}{black}
\colorlet{fadedtoc}{green}% just for (more) clarity in the example. yellow=yuck!
\colorlet{ontoc}{blue}% just for clarity in the example

\begin{document}

  Main title page goes here.

  \maintoc

  \chapter{Chapter One}
  \section{A section}
  \section{Another section}

  \packetpart
  \chapter{Chapter Two}
  \section{A middle section}
  \section{Another middle section}

  \packetpart
  \chapter{Chapter Three}
  \section{A later section}
  \section{Another later section}

  \packetpart
  \chapter{Chapter Four}
  \section{An almost latest section}
  \section{A latest section}

\end{document}
```

> [image: toc main]

---

> [image: toc 2]

---

> [image: toc 3]

---

> [image: toc 4]

Comment: Thanks very much! Especially, since I know that Christian bugged you (on my behalf) to look at this ;). This is really helpful. I actually redefined `\addcontentsline` to avoid needing to redefine `\normalcolor`. I'm not sure if that is better, but it seemed a bit more limited. Though then you need `\colorlet{toccol}{}` in the manager command and to add `\color{toccol}`. Could you explain what `\cfr@removetonil` etc. is doing? I realise that it somehow enables you to avoid using the tag stuff and messing around with the `packetcount` counter, but I don't really understand how it is doing so.

Comment: imho, it is a bug of the standard classes that they use `\normalcolor` for the TOC page numbers (for sections, subsections... in `book`,  but not for  chapters, for subsections ... in `article` but not for sections). The redefinition of `\normalcolor` is only active during the various TOCs. The `\addcontentsline` redefinition is active throughout the document, but in retrospect my worries about `hyperref` do not apply to documents destined to be stapled!! If `etoc` was used also to customize the line styles, there would be no issue. Or, `tocloft` is a good option here.

Comment: `\cfr@removetonil`:  the `.toc` file is simply executed at each toc occurence in the document. The macro is a delimited macro (`LaTeX` has no interface for user definition of such macros, deliberately obfuscating most of the power of the underlying `TeX` language). The `\AtEndDocument` inserts an end mark at the end of the `.toc` file. The `\cfr@removetonil` will find everything till this end mark and make it vanish. For the very last packet though, and for the main TOC, no `\cfr@removetonil` is executed, hence an innocuous definition is given to `\cfr@nil`, whose expansion thus does nothing.

Comment: and I should have done rather `\let\cfr@nil\@empty` to take less of `TeX`'s memory...

Comment: about the approach with `tag`'s: one would after the main toc issue `\etocsettagdepth{packettag}{none}` for each of the packets, and then at each packet one would only need to issue `\etocsettagdepth{thispackettag}{chapter}`. This method would avoid the `\cfr@removetonil` hack. But the color management could be handled by etoc's tags only via hacking `etoc`'s internal macro `\Etoc@depthtag@` to extend its action to, in this case, setting the color, and not only setting the `tocdepth`. There are some comments in the `etoc` code.

Comment: Thanks. I just wanted to know if using the tags to handle the non-colour stuff was problematic in this case. (Because then I would alter my actual code.) If not, I may keep using the tag stuff for that, and use my modification of your code for the colour stuff (so I don't need to redefine `\normalcolor`). Thanks again for your time on this!

Comment: @cfr I am glad `etoc` has some use. See my updated answer for using tags.

Comment: I finally realised what the `remove` stuff is doing, and I would upvote this again if they'd let me give you 2 votes. I'm sure `etoc` would be even more useful if I actually took the time to learn it. (I don't typeset ToCs very often at all.)

Comment: Actually, I'm wrong. For some reason, I don't seem to need that and it still works. Hmmm.

Comment: @cfr the winning team is `tocloft+etoc`. With `tocloft` you have a good interface to customize the standard TOCs. With `etoc` you have an easy way to have multiple and local tables of contents, and then you can also do simple tricks with either tags or labelled-and-used-elsewhere tocs (this could have been another approach to your problem, by the way), or the "shuffling" of levels. True, with `etoc` you can also customize to the ultimate the TOCs, but this requires re-designing everything from the bare "name", "number", and "page number". I did not understand your last comment about `remove`.